# Facebook graph api places query by name with OR condition

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/places/web/search/) for facebook graph search api for places q= to query for the name of the business.  Is it possible to have a q=cafe OR q=restaurant if I want to search for business that are either cafe or restaurants.  Basically is there a way to query the facebook graph api when searching for places that match OR condition?  Or is that 2 separate queries for each search term for name?

Searching by category would not work as I need to search for a specific niche business type.

Comment: No, there is no OR, or another way to search for multiple terms at the same time. You will need to make two queries.

Comment: Ok thanks for responding!